# Display table where foreign keys are values from second column of referenced tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, join, naming-conventions

Is it possible to write such a universal query? By universal I mean that I won't need to type column names that are foreigns keys, so that I can use this query for other tables. Simple example:

```
[table workers]
ID [PK] | worker | department [FK]
--------+--------+-----------
1       | Smith  | 2

[table departments]
ID [PK] | department
--------+------------+
1       | Paris      |
2       | Oslo       |
```

After `SELECT/JOIN` query it would be displayed as:

```
ID [PK] | worker | department [FK]
--------+--------+-----------
1       | Smith  | Oslo
```

But instead of writing:

```
SELECT workers.ID, workers.worker, departments.department
FROM workers JOIN departments ON workers.department = departments.ID;
```

which would work only for `workers` and `departments` I'd prefer something more universal like:

```
SELECT * FROM [tableName] JOIN [referenced table#1], 
[referenced table#2]...[#n] 
ON [tableName].FK#1 = [referenced table#1].[2nd column], 
[tableName].FK#2 = [referenced table#2].[2nd column]...#n
```

where `#n` - number of foreign keys and their referenced tables which varies for every table.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve or provide an example. Do you want to generalize the binary JOIN to an n-ary JOIN? In your example, you seem to type foreign key column names as often as you would do when using a standard SQL join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly, at least not without a function using sophisticated [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql+postgresql).

But with a **proper naming convention**, you can simplify things along these lines:

```
[table worker]
worker_id [PK] | worker | department_id [FK]
----------------+--------+-----------
1               | Smith  | 2
```

```
[table department]
department_id [PK] | department
---------------------+------------
1                    | Paris
2                    | Oslo
```

Using `id` as column name is generally a very bad idea. It is not descriptive. Unfortunately, some ORMs spread this anti-pattern.

Now, **if** only columns that are supposed to, to the left and right of a JOIN, have matching names then you could employ a rarely used standard-SQL feature: [**`NATURAL JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

> `NATURAL` is shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in the
>   two tables that have the same names.

Makes for very simple code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   worker
NATURAL JOIN department
```

I hardly ever use this, though. It **can become a trap** if you change table columns later and introduce unintended matches. If that can't happen in your case, go for it.

At least you can use the simpler JOIN syntax with `USING`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   worker     
JOIN   department USING (department_id)
```

There was a [closely related question on dba.SE recently.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51781/can-postgres-raise-warnings-if-joins-are-inconsistant-with-foreign-keys)